# How to create direct DoubleBuffer from byte array

Tags: java, opengl-es, buffer

I have the following code which creates an *indirect* DoubleBuffer from a Byte array.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais;
Byte doubleGeomByteArray[];
DoubleBuffer dbb;
...
doubleGeomByteArray[] = new byte[ByteBuffer.wrap(intBuffer).order(endian).getInt() * 2 * 8];
bais.read(doubleGeomByteArray); //reads from ByteArrayInputStream into byte array
dbb = ByteBuffer.wrap(doubleGeomByteArray).order(endian).asDoubleBuffer();
```

This works well, however I need dbb to be *direct*, as it will be used with OpenGL ES

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the else statement could also be used by itself as it will catch either byte order, just wanted to show two different ways of doing virtually the same thing. The top one is only if the data byte order matches native.

```
if (endian.equals(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())){
    interimByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(doubleGeomByteArray.length);
    dbb = interimByteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer();
    interimByteBuffer.put(doubleGeomByteArray);
}
else{
    interimByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(doubleGeomByteArray).order(endian);
    dbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numOfPoints * 2 * 8).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asDoubleBuffer();
    while(interimByteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        dbb.put(interimByteBuffer.getDouble());
    }
    dbb.flip();
}
```